# Port mirroring/monitoring the DSL/ATM interface on a Cisco 877/877W?

Tags: cisco, monitoring, adsl

Is it possible to mirror/monitor the DSL interface (atm/dialer interfaces) to one of the fastethernet ports on this device?

Running software:
Cisco IOS Software, C870 Software (C870-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.4(11)XJ3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Comment: Am I being dim or are you trying to mirror ATM traffic over ethernet? really not sure that's going to work myself.

Comment: Yeah pretty much, and neither am I. Thought maybe someone else might know if there's some way this can be achieved :-).

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a definite answer either way

```
monitor session 1 source interface atm0
monitor session 1 destination interface fastethernet 0/1
```

Have you tried something like the above?

Whilst the document isn't specific to your router, this [Cisco document](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps708/products_tech_note09186a008015c612.shtml) may be of interest to you

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for monitoring the fastethernet interfaces.

Comment: In which case, I would guess it's not possible to mirror from and to different interface types